# Is it possible to move OEM Office to another hard drive by copying the OS using Acronis or similar?

Tags: microsoft-office, oem, acronis-trueimage, licensing

I have run out of space on my current hard drive and purchased a new larger drive.  My old OS has an OEM install of Office 2013.  If I use Acronis or a similar disk copying tool to move the OS to the larger drive, will my copy of Office still be licensed?

I cannot re-activate Office. The key was only good for a single activation.

Comment: I didn't think single activation keys existed for Office. Are you sure you have a key that's only good for a single activation? (You may have to telephone activate and explain that the old drive died.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Yes. I called Microsoft, then the reseller. My workplace purchased an OEM key with one activation. This is making it difficult to upgrade me to a larger drive.

Comment: If you replace the original drive with the new, larger drive, you should not have licensing problems if this is the only hardware change. Do a track-by-track copy first. If this is OK, you can then start moving and expanding partitions. Make sure you keep the old drive, so that you have something to go back to.

Comment: If you are able to mount both drives, you can leave your system directories where they are (Windows, Program Files, etc), but move your Users and other data directories to the new disc. This should give you a workable amount of storage.

Answer (score 0):

You should not need to re-activate. I use a tool called Partition Magic all the time. I connect the two drives via USB to another computer and run the wizard. The activations with Windows and other microsoft products are usually tied to an HAL file which is a hardware identifier. Basically this won't change for a hard drive swap. It will kick in if you try to take your hard drive and plug it into another computer since the hardware obviously changed.